# iPhone X overheating after drop on floor

Tags: iphone, battery, screen

I dropped my iPhone X and a 1cm vertical stripe of the OLED screen got super bright white so that in I had to tape it in order to continue to use my phone. Now I also noticed that the phone also in normal use gets really hot and fast battery drain. I was thinking to get a new screen on iFixit but I don`t know if it will fix the issue?
Thanks

Comment: It's extremely difficult to troubleshoot hardware problems here but it really looks like something broke loose when the iPhone was dropped.  I'm assuming you've done the usual "turn it off and back on" routine.  You can take it to iFixIt or other similar, authorized Apple repair store and have them take a look at it.